# How to get Expiry date from the SSL Certificate file in PHP

Tags: php, ssl

I want to get the expiry date from the SSL Certificate file. There is a web page in PHP that I've created, in which user can upload his SSL Certificate file and I will have to get the expiry date of that file using PHP.

Comment: See: http://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=755

Comment: It gets the expiration date and time of the current certificate. I want to get the expiration date and time for any certificate that is supplied by the user.

Comment: you can modify it... see `man x509` and read about the flag `-in`

Answer (score 35):

The code below should help:

```
    $url = "https://www.google.com";
    $orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
    $read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
    $cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
    $certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($certinfo);
    echo '</pre>';
```

The expiry date should be under $certinfo['validTo'] field.

Comment: this is very helpful but i think it's very slow with multiple domains.

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me:

```
$url = "https://www.google.com";
$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 
30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($certinfo);
echo '</pre>';
```

fine ssl expire time in this fild

```
[validTo_time_t] => 1523164135 // expire time.
```

Convert Date & Time

```
$valid_from = date(DATE_RFC2822,$certinfo['validFrom_time_t']);
$valid_to = date(DATE_RFC2822,$certinfo['validTo_time_t']);
echo "Valid From: ".$valid_from."<br>";
echo "Valid To:".$valid_to."<br>";
```

Result:

Valid From:    Mon, 09 Oct 2017 07:00:00 +0700
 Valid To:      Wed, 10 Oct 2018 06:59:59 +0700

Comment: This code is working great, nice and simple!
However... it fails with a string of PHP errors on domains that are not running SSL. I've never used streams like this before, how can one wrap some soft error checking in there so we can fail gracefully if theres no SSL web server to connect to?

Answer (score 13):

```
$certpath = "your_certificate.cer";
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents($certpath));
if( $certinfo['validFrom_time_t'] > time() || $certinfo['validTo_time_t'] < time() )
    print "Certificate is expired.";
```