# Get SSL expiry date Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, ssl-certificate

I am trying to build a Google Spreadsheet that will warn any of the upcoming expiry dates on SSLs.

I would like a Google Script to fetch the certificate for a supplied URL and extract the expiry date from it.

Google Scripts are written in a version of JavaScript. I have access to [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) which allows me to make HTTP requests but I cannot find anything in the headers about the SSL certificate.

I, obviously, don't have access to `openssl` which I would normally use to get this information.

My question is, what should I be querying to get the certificate info?

**Edit**

If someone knows of a free API I could use, that would be a viable alternative.

Comment: This is not a Google Script, but you can get an idea here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863948) on how to get how to get expiry date from the SSL Certificate. You can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679920) that use javascript in getting the SSL certificate.

Comment: thanks @KENdi , Unfortunately, I have come across both of those articles. The node version just calls openssl as a child process, the php one has access to PHP Curl which has in built support for querying SSL certificates. Unfortunately, neither is an option on a google script as far as I know.

Comment: @JonathanHodgson were you able to create this sheet?